# Managing Web applications in Tomcat by command line

Tags: java, tomcat, web, command-line, tomcat6

I have configured Tomcat6 on RHEL6. I have several war files deployed and the web server is up and running. I could log into the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" after configuring $catalina.home/conf/tomcat-user.xml appropriately, which looks like below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <tomcat-users>

   <role rolename="tomcat"/>
   <role rolename="role1"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
   <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
   <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

   <user name="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager" />

 </tomcat-users>
```

I used the following to command to stop the "/httpif" application, but didn't work.

```
 wget http://tomcat:password@localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/httpif
```

Error what I got was 401 unauthorized.

```
--2014-03-05 14:28:23--  http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/httpif
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

Can anyone help me how do I get through this.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Title Says Managing by Command line, than why you are using web managment?? you may want to correct it to get accurate reply.

Comment: Yes, I do want to manage meaning start, stop, deploy, undeploy.. all by command line instructions, so that this can scripted away. I think I've a proper title. u can edit the title if you can word it more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the role `manager-gui` to the tomcat user and change its password to `password="password"`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <tomcat-users>

   <role rolename="tomcat"/>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
   <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
   <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

 </tomcat-users>
```

Comment: manager-gui is for tomcat7, read the post he is talking about tomcat6 :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing the auth parameter correctly. correct syntax for wget is:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/whatever/ --user=tomcat --password=password
```

don't uncomment the whole block just add these lines in block to add a single user, if one user work other will work. start with simple :-)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="test" password="test" roles="manager-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting the exact localhost url in above as i don't know how to write localhost your here it ask me to provide full domain name here :-) hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but it didn't work for me.. :( same error.. 401 Unauthorized

Comment: try to add one user and than others.

Comment: The issue had been with manager-gui role not being present in users. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to know, but strange thing is if you didn't define the role manager-gui in tomcat-user and how can it be accessible via Tomcat Application Manager from web. perhaps you have define the same tomcat user two times, using from web you used tomcat tomcat with role tomcat and when you used wget you used tomcat password with manager role which created issue. enjoy